# Responsive design using bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I have two different layouts for desktop and mobile view. Here is how they look like
[image]

I have written this code so far, but it is not exactly how I need it to be. I don't know how to switch block C and D in mobile view

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-1"> 
    <div class="row col col-lg-10"> 
       <div class="col-3 bg-secondary">A</div> 
          <div class="col-9 "> 
             <div class="row bg-success p-1"> B</div> 
             <div class="row bg-primary order-lg-2 p-1">D</div> 
          </div> 
       </div> 
       <div class="col col-lg-2"> 
          <div class="col bg-warning p-1">C</div> 
       </div> 
</div>
```

I need to use Bootstrap grids. Any idea on how to start?

Comment: Are you sure you want block C after D in mobile view

Comment: yes and this is what I am stuck at!

Comment: Well i can easily tell you but C will be in between B and D in mobile view

Comment: I already have that in my code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order-xx-N` to reorder element at screen , bootstrap has mediaquerie built-in. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/

Possible example

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 bg-secondary mb-auto">A
      <p class="d-lg-none bg-light">Mobile layout</p>
      <p class="d-none d-lg-block bg-info">Desktop layout</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-9">
      <div class="col col-lg-9 bg-success p-1">B</div>
      <div class="col order-1 p-1  bg-primary ">C</div>
      <div class="col-12  bg-warning p-1  order-lg-2">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I had not thought about reordering at screen

Comment: just noticed a slight difference with my layout. Block C should be in mobile view below D but A should not be on its left.

Comment: @SofiaLazrak that is the case here, what have you done different on your side ? Where did you confuse with order and col class ?

Comment: This: 
<div class="row row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-1">
       <div class="row col col-lg-10">
          <div class="col-3 bg-secondary">A</div>
           <div class="col-9 ">
              <div class="row bg-success p-1"> B</div>
              <div class="row  bg-primary  order-lg-2 p-1">D</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col col-lg-2">
          <div class="col bg-warning p-1">C</div>
       </div>
    </div>
It is still not doing it because D should be taking 100% of the width

Comment: Can you build a jsfiddle or codepen to see it happening live ? https://jsfiddle.net - http://codepen.io/pen At first, your structure is different and c stands alone in a second column. it can not work and is different from the structure i have set in the answer ;) (in my answer B,C,D are sibblings, not in your code)

Comment: yes thank you. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/6op5h9f2/

Comment: my solution is not 100% right because D should  be the length of B and C in Desktop view. Can you suggest how it can be done?

Comment: @SofiaLazrak like i answered, you need an HTML structure that is compatible with flex-wrap where B, C and D are siblings inside a column(style as a row too) and A standing alone aside as a single column. Your code is not similar with the solution i proposed, therefore it won't work.